# Failure to run the program when converting the variable c

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import sys
EPSILON = 1e-15

c = float(sys.argv[1])

t = c

while abs(t - c/t) > (EPSILON*t):

    t = (c/t + t)/2.0

print(t)
```

At the time of executing the program, the message below is given

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sama_User\Desktop\1.py", line 3, in <module>
    c = float(sys.argv[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you passing arguments to your program ? Check the erroneous line `c = float(sys.argv[1])`. You need to run the program like `python 1.py arg1` in order to access `arg1`